# Is it possible to wait until celery group done?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, messagebroker

I am trying to do group tasks and wait until all the group subtasks finished then run the last task. But when I call task it calls group and last tasks but the last task finished before group finish. Is it possible to wait until all the tasks inside group finish?

```
@shared_task(name="print")
def print_order():
    print("PRINT #1")
    mylist = [(1, 2), (4, 6), (1, 4)]
    group([(add.s(*i) | order_id_print.s()) for i in mylist]).delay()


@shared_task(name="print.add")
def add(x,y):
    print("ADD #2")
    chain(add_task1.s(x, y, 'task id') | add_task2.si(x, y, "task_id")).delay()
    return x+y

@shared_task(name="add_task_1")
def add_task1(order_id, ftype, task_id):
    print("ADD task #2-1")
    print("add tasks task1 order_id {} {} {}".format(order_id, ftype, task_id))

@shared_task(name="add_task_2")
def add_task2(order_id, ftype, task_id):
    print("ADD task #2-2")
    print("add tasks task2 order_id {} {} {}".format(order_id, ftype, task_id))


@shared_task(name="print.order_id_print")
def order_id_print(id):
    print("ORDER #3")
    print("order id is {}".format(id))
```

Comment: Not so long ago I was asking the same question on the Celery IRC channel at FreeNode. They explained to me that the best thing to do is to make a chain out of your group and add a task that collects the data (or processes the results of a group).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want, is a chord instead of a group. A chord is a task that only executes after all of the tasks in a group have finished executing.

Have a look at the docs:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords

Comment: So in my case, if i use chord, after all the `add` task finished then `order_id_print` will invoke?

Comment: correct. something like `chord([add.s(*i) for i in mylist], order_id_print.s()).delay()` will asynchronously run all the `add` tasks. When all `add` tasks are finished, it will asynchronously invoke your `order_id_print` task. Beware that Celery will pass all individual `add` results to `order_id_print` as a list so you have to add some tasks arguments.

Comment: I did exactly as it is, but in celery, it shows `ADD task #2-2` right after `order_id_print`. Got the celery results like this

[2019-04-11 17:14:45,475: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] ORDER #3

[2019-04-11 17:14:45,476: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] order id is [5, 3, 10]

[2019-04-11 17:14:45,476: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task 
print.order_id_print[77b50397-a2bb-4141-8380-e86aa1c04642] succeeded in 0.0006398810000973754s: None
[2019-04-11 17:14:45,476: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
add_task_2[30fbbf70-cae8-482c-81fd-fdc17a816f48]

Comment: that is because you _asynchronously_ trigger another task (chain) within your `add` task. If this is not what you want, you need to rearrange your workflows.

Comment: Oh, i get it. So instead of calling `add` i have to call `add_task1` and `add_task2` in chord right? so that way there wont be any third async process ??? but it needed to be inside for loop so inside `chord` there should be group ? like `chord([(add_task1(*i), add_task2(*i)) for i in my_list], order_id_print.s()).delay()`

Comment: correct, you have to call `add_task1` and `add_task2` in the header (the first part of the chord). As to your second question, I have never tried to invoke chains in a group or a chord header, so I'd say give it a try and report back here! If it does not work, there's always an alternative (e.g. as an alternatively to a chain, asynchronously call the next task from within your first task, that kind of stuff. It all depends on your exact requirements.

Comment: How am i going to call this task automatically after some N minutes ? like after all the tasks finished i want to call this task like 5 minutes for example. I perceived that using celery beat does not suit for this kind of job because sometimes current job might not finished at that time when celerybeat starts

Answer (score 0):

For this there is 2 options: **''group'' and "chord"(Chord does not work with rpc)** . Both are celery constructs that allow you to run multiple tasks in parallel and then wait until all tasks have completed.

with chord it is possible to define a ''callback'' task and do the whole process asynchronously. If your server needs to wait for tasks before return to the client then group may be the best option

**Group:**

```py
tasks = [get_foods.s(x,y), get_drinks.s(z,w)]
results = group(tasks)().get() #lock until everything done
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

**Chord:**

```
chord([get_foods.s(x,y), get_drinks.s(x,y)], finish_order.s()).delay()
```